# Error while checking user input through regex in java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to let a user enter some text and then search for a pattern within that text. The program works fine when I don't use any checks. However, I want the user to just enter characters in text/pattern. I'm new to regex and I tried the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * The following program asks user to key in some text, creates and stores a suffix table from that text, 
 * and sorts it out. Then it asks user to key in another text, referred to as pattern; 
 * and searches for that pattern in the text. 
 * If it finds even one instance of the pattern, a console message of pattern found is displayed to the user
 * If not, a message saying pattern not found is displayed.
 */

public class SearchInSuffixTable {

private static Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );

/**
 * This is the main method. It stores the suffixes from $text into $suffixTable, 
 * calls out sortSuffixTab method to sort the table and then searches for $pattern in suffixTable using binarySearch method. 
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text, pattern;


    System.out.println("Enter the text:");
    while(!in.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z]+"))
    {
        System.out.println("inside loop");
        System.out.println("Invalid character. Only alphabets are permitted");
        in.next();
    }
    text = in.next();

    System.out.println(text);

    System.out.println("Enter the pattern to be searched:");
    while(!in.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z]+"))
    {
        System.out.println("inside pattern's loop");
        System.out.println("Invalid character. Only alphabets are permitted");
        in.next();
    }
    pattern = in.next();

    int n = text.length();

    String[] suffixTable = new String[n];

    for(int index=0; index<n; index++)
    {
        suffixTable[index] = text.substring(index);
    }

    //calling the sort function on the suffix table to sort out the elements in alphabetical order.
    sortSuffixTab(suffixTable);

    System.out.println("The Suffix Table for the text provided:");
    System.out.println("Index\tSuffix");
    for(int index=0; index<n; index++)
        System.out.println((index+1) + "\t" + suffixTable[index]);

    System.out.println("Searching for the pattern...\n");
    if(binarySearch(suffixTable, pattern, 0, n-1)) //calling the search function to search for pattern inside the text
        System.out.println("Pattern found");
    else
        System.out.println("Pattern not found");
}
```

But what the program does is - It accepts the text but goes in an infinite loop while accepting the pattern.
And, if I enter non-acceptable text input, it goes in an infinite loop there as well. Not sure, whether the problem is in regex or in using the scanner.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `^` from your pattern, which means the beginning of a line. Not sure, but i think this is true only for the beginning of all your input, then it simply splits by delimiter(whitespaces by default), so that tokens cannot signal about beginning of the line. And i think `^` in your case is useless at all. Also note that you should *minimize scope of variables*, so you need to review making your `Scanner` as a field.

Comment: wow! The little edit worked like a charm. I still don't understand how though. So, with '^' in pattern, the new text I was entering wasn't ending up as token? But i tried a print in the loop, it was displaying the new token.

Comment: ' So, with '^' in pattern, the new text I was entering wasn't ending up as token?' — no, the point is, although not sure, that `Scanner` class simply splits(like `String.split`) all your input by whitespaces, so after this, beginning of the line can be recognize only in the beginning of all input. The problem was that pattern in your second loop never matched.